# Halting problem of Turing machine in at most f(|x|) steps

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

I've been looking into and learning variants of the halting/acceptance problem of Turing Machine, and was wondering if there is a problem defined as:

*{< M,x >|M halts on input x in at most f(|x|) steps, where |x| is the length of x and f(|x|) is a deterministic function of |x|}*

Comment: Now that you have defined it, there is.

Comment: Ah, but as I'm still learning, I don't know the complexity class it belongs to and if my proof sketch is correct, my guess is EXPTIME-complete. But I'm not sure and wanted to take a look at existing references (if any).

Comment: It depends a lot on how `f` is defined. I see you represent `x` in unary (as you use only `|x|`), so if `f = Id` the problem is in `P`. if `f(1^n) = 1 ^ (2^n))` it's indeed EXPTIME-complete. In general, it's in `DTIME(f(n))` but not in `DTIME(g(n))` where `g(n) = o(f(n))`  .

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: No problem. by the way, this exact language is used to prove the **time hierarchy**, which states that for every `g, f` such that `g(n) = o(f(n))`, `DTIME(g(n)) != DTIME(f(n))`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem

Comment: Thanks! Might I ask if you know about any comprehensive list of EXPTIME-complete problems? I know the generalized games problems, but they are unintuitive for me and I was unable to find any good such lists of problems.

Comment: Sadly, I don't. The basic complete problem for a DTIME(f(n)) class is the language you have provided, and I don't know of more complete EXPTIME languages except from generalized games. Note that this does not mean there are only a few complete problems - we can easily manufacture infinitely many such languages from a given complete language. But I don't know more intuitive EXPTIME-complete languages.